# Template parameter type deduction for pointer vs. nullptr_t

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction

Consider the following C++ program:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

namespace {
template <typename Result, typename... Arg>
Result call_fn(std::function<Result(Arg...)> fn, Arg&&... arg) {
    return fn(std::forward<Arg>(arg)...);
}

std::string test_fn(int, std::string*) {
    return "hello, world!";
}
}

int main(int, char**) {
    std::cout << call_fn(std::function(test_fn), 0, nullptr) << "\n";

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is a bit of a contrived example, but I've run into the same problem while trying to implement something vaguely similar to `std::make_unique`. When compiling this program, I get the following error:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Weverything -Werror -Wno-c++98-compat call_fn.cpp
call_fn.cpp:19:18: error: no matching function for call to 'call_fn'
    std::cout << call_fn(std::function(test_fn), 0, nullptr) << "\n";
                 ^~~~~~~
call_fn.cpp:9:8: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'Arg' (<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> *> vs. <int, nullptr_t>)
Result call_fn(std::function<Result(Arg...)> fn, Arg&&... arg) {
       ^
1 error generated.
```

The problem seems to be that the type for the pointer parameter is deduced to be `nullptr_t`, not `std::string*`. I can "fix" this by adding a `static_cast`, or by explicitly specifying the template parameters to `call_fn`, but I find that level of verbosity distasteful.

Is there a way to modify the definition of `call_fn` such that type deduction will work better for pointer parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the conflict in deduction rules for `Arg...` on one hand the `std::function<...>` defines it on the other the input arguments define it.

You should just use `std::invoke` instead of `call_fn` or use `typename... Args2` for input parameters. Or you can drop the requirement for input to be a `std::function` and just accept any callable.

Another option is to ensure that the input parameters aren't used for argument type deduction but I am uncertain how to do so with variadic templates (`typename...`) - have some doubts about syntax.

Edit: let me write an example

```
     template<typename T> foo(std::vector<T> x, T y);

     std::vector<double> x;
     int y;
     foo(x,y);
```

Here `foo` will not be able to deduce `T` due to conflict. One of ways to resolve it is by ensuring that `y` is not used in type deduction.

```
    template<typename T> 
    struct same_type_impl { type=T;};

    template<typename T>
     using same_type = typename same_type_impl<T>::type;

    template<typename T> foo(std::vector<T> x, same_type<T> y);

     std::vector<double> x;
     int y;
     foo(x,y);
```

Here `foo` will deduce `T` as `double`.

Comment: This almost works, but same_type seems to interfere with perfect forwarding, sometimes (it's not really clear to me why it works sometimes, and not others). For some uses, I get an error like `no known conversion from 'int' to 'same_type<int> &&' (aka 'int &&')`. I'll play with it and see if I can get a minimal example of this...

Comment: @CmdrMoozy `same_type<int>&&` is not a "perfectly forwarded `int`" but instead it is an r-value reference to `int`. Since function dictates the types you cannot suddenly change them to something else unless you do so manually. If you want flexibility with input then you should accept input as `typename... Args2` and preferably apply some SFINEA requirements on it to ensure that it doesn't differ much from `typename... Args`.

Answer (score 0):

From my testing I think `std::function` is the culprit here. It's too strict on the types with variadic templates, somehow (i assume).

The following works:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

namespace {

template <typename FnT, typename... Arg>
auto call_fn(FnT fn, Arg&&... arg) {
    return fn(std::forward<Arg>(arg)...);
}

std::string test_fn(int, std::string*) { return "hello, world!"; }

}  // namespace

int main(int, char**) {
    std::cout << call_fn(test_fn, 0, nullptr) << "\n";

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Like this, we just template away the `std::function`, the only requirement now is that the function we give accepts those arguments and is callable (`operator()`).